# Painting on a JButton in java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a mancala game board. For the purpose of the game, is there any way I can create a JButton and then just paint on it? I don't want to use setIcon property

Comment: Didnt this work? `jbutton.setBackground(color);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom class which extends from `JButton` and then override it's `paintComponent` method

See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details

Remember though, a button typically has a lot going on, borders, content etc, this makes performing custom painting on them a little more tricky..